Multibib not allowing a common source for different bibliographies without a Warning
Assume a typical situation where you have a big data basis of references in a unique bib file, say references.bib. Then, within one single tex file, say main.tex, you want to create two distinct lists of references. You may use multilib for that with \newcites, as \cite_list1 and \cite_list2. The problem is that you cannot make calls to the same reference in references.bib, say ref_a, i.e., \cite_list1{ref_a} and \cite_list2{ref_a}, for the two lists, which is a basic need for me (The two list would contain some different but also some identical references), without getting those annoying warnings. That works, but the warnings are clearly pathological... Think of writing a book with different chapters requiring different lists of references, all taken from a common data source file (bib); currently multilib does not seem to allow that without warning.
See this code, which runs on Overleaf:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\title{Multiple Bibliographies with \texttt{multibib}}
\author{LianTze Lim, modified by Chris}
\date{}

\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{Math,Phys}{Math Readings,Physics Reading}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cite{paper1} and \cite{paper2} were published later than \citeMath{paper3} and \citePhys{paper4}. \\
$\rightarrow$ That works fine!

\citePhys{paper3} is the most advanced. \\
$\rightarrow$ That does \emph{not} work properly:

Problem: Warning "Label `paper3' multiply defined. You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \textbackslash{}label{...} labels only one item." 

I understand why: That is because I am using for Phys a reference that was already used for Math. However, that is a bit absurd, because that means that one cannot use a common data bibliography source to create different lists of references, which is probably a most common need -- at least mine! -- without getting that warning. How can such a warning be eliminated?

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\bibliographystyleMath{unsrt}
\bibliographyMath{refs-etc}

\bibliographystylePhys{unsrt}
\bibliographyPhys{refs-etc}

\end{document}


Can you please describe your question in the question body and not just in the code?

Please make your code so we can compile it to reproduce the problem. Either use .bib files everyone has or include a minimal .bib in your question. Is Biblatex an option? I ask because it can do this without generating warnings. Although it might require different markup, thinking about it.

I found the solution, using also the package bibunits:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document
That works like a charm!
